# Converting Obj-C Dictionary to Swift 2 Dictionary

Tags: objective-c, dictionary, swift2

In my Obj-C application there was a dictionary as below

```
   NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey,
        [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey,
        nil];
```

I am unable to convert it Swift-2 dictionary

Comment: And what's the question? Are you having trouble _forming_ the dictionary in the first place and you just want to know how? Do you not _know_ how to write a dictionary in Swift? Did you try it and you got a compile error? What?

Answer (score 3):

It is completely unclear what your question is. A dictionary in Swift is formed by this syntax:

```
let d = [key1:value1, key2:value2]
```

In your code, the two keys are CFStrings, and Swift for some reason doesn't always get that this is the same as an NSString, so you have to cast to String explicitly. Apart from that, it's straightforward:

```
let options = [
    kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey as String:true,
    kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey as String:true
]
```

But since you don't show any context, it is unclear whether that will get you where you want to go; you'll have to try it and see.